# Is it safe to use MPI_Isend in this C example of code?

Tags: c, mpi

Quick question: Due to performance requirements I need to be able to do later calclulations while I am also sending data.
So I need to use MPI_Isend.

Is this safe?

```
 //qtasks[][] is a 2d array and Im sending one row to each task 
//it has numtasks rows and different count of columns for each row
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
int k;
for(t=0;t<numtasks;t++){
        if(t != rank) {
            _k= cqtasks[t]; //this is the number of columns (for each row)                 
            MPI_Isend( qtasks[t],_k,MPI_DOUBLE, t, 55,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpireq );
            MPI_Request_free( &mpireq );

        }
    }
```

Comment: No.  http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/dont-leak-mpi_requests http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/mpi_request_free-is-evil

Comment: As long as you do not need the `qtasks` data while doing these later calculations, all you have to do is place a `MPI_Waitall` after your calculations (and before you need the `qtasks` data). You'll be overlapping communication with computation.

Answer (score 1):

No. On the one side, and as Jonathan Dursi pointed out, MPI_Request_free deallocates the request and therefore this call does not ensure that the message has actually reached its destination.

To make sure that the message has arrived, you need to use either MPI_Wait or MPI_Test calls (or any of their relatives - MPI_Waitall, MPI_Waitsome, ... MPI_Testall, MPI_Testsome, ...). So your code may look something like:

```
//qtasks[][] is a 2d array and Im sending one row to each task 
//it has numtasks rows and different count of columns for each row
MPI_Request mpireq[N];
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
int _k;
for(t=0;t<size;t++){
        if(t != rank) {
            _k= cqtasks[t]; //this is the number of columns (for each row)                 
            MPI_Isend( qtasks[t],_k,MPI_DOUBLE, t, 55,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpireq[t] );    
        }
    }

do_some_calculation();

for(t=0;t<size;t++){
        if(t != rank) {
            MPI_Wait (mpireq[t], MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @Tasos. If the answer is correct for you, indicate that by voting it up and/or clicking the check mark on the left side of the screen. That way future visitors will also know that this is the correct answer. You'll also earn a few rep for doing so.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is going to be 100% correct though. If you're going to be completely safe, you should probably use `MPI_Waitall` instead of `MPI_Wait`. That way the sends can all make progress at the same time. On most implementations, it probably doesn't matter though.

Comment: Yeah... that probably changes between MPI implementations. Thanks for the tip. I basically chose the MPI_Wait approach to simplify the code.